# git - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I am not able to install git on Ubuntu 12.10.
I have tried adding the git package repository manually to software sources still I am getting the following error while installing git-core on Ubuntu 12.10

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git-core : Depends: git (> 1:1.7.0.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried ti install git too, but now this error is being displayed

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
[sudo] password for vishak: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I also updated the repositories, by running sudo apt-get update, but still the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to add any repositories to your `sources.list` as `git` already comes with any version of ubuntu since hardy.

`git-core` used to be the old name for the central package, and has been replaced by the `git` package since oneric.

finally, `aptitude` usually does a better job when it comes to resolving dependencies, so you might use it instead (and from the cmdline, the syntax is almost identical to that of `apt-get`)

if you don't have `aptitude` installed, do so by running

```
 $ sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and then install git:

```
 $ sudo aptitude install git
```

**EDIT**
after removing any extranous lines from your sources.list, you should refresh your package cache.

```
$ sudo aptitude update
```

if aptitude cannot find `liberror-perl` which has been in ubuntu since hardy (and never changed since then), you probably have broken your `sources.list` file.

Comment: I tried that too but getting the following error! :(

Comment: `$sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages `

Comment: better update your question (by *adding* the new information rather than replacing the old info with the new one); anyhow i'll update my answer

Comment: `sudo aptitude update
[sudo] password for vishak: 
sudo: aptitude: command not found`

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: Should I try installing aptitude first..?

Comment: yes, i would suggest that.

Comment: E: Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate :(

Comment: i really think you have broken your `sources.list` file and removed the official repositories. undo that change. make sure the original apt-sources are listed. run `apt-get update` to refresh the package cache. start installing.

Comment: you just need to change the 'download from' server from ubuntu s/w center... your regional mirror is the problem

Comment: @Fridous is totally right, simply change your source mirror